# NoMethodError in Codecademy Rails Tutorial Threadly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to resolve this error for three days now. I've checked several other questions concerning the NoMethod Error. They're usually solved by fixing a the spelling of one variable to match another. So I think that I'm not yet familiar enough with the ways that the various files relate to pinpoint which variable doesn't match its counterpart.

app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index 
    @new_post = Post.new 
    @all_posts = Post.order(created_at: :desc).all 
  end
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  root 'posts#index'
end
```

app/views/posts/index.html.erb

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>threadly</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Form goes here -->
    <%= form_for(@new_post) do |f| %>  
      <div class="field"> 
        <%= f.label :comment %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :comment %>  
      </div> 
      <div class="actions"> 
        <%= f.submit "Create" %> 
      </div> 
    <% end %>

    <ul class="comments"> 
      <% @all_posts.each do |p| %> 
      <li><%= p.comment %></li>
      <% end %> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

db/migrate/((migration file))

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.text :comment
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the text of the error message:

```
NoMethodError in Posts#index

Showing /home/ccuser/workspace/learn-rails_threadly/threadly/app/views/posts/index.html.erb where line #14 raised:

undefined method `comment' for #<Post id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Then it shows an extracted source from the html file, with the following line highlighted:

```
<%= f.text_area :comment %>
```

Followed by:

```
Rails.root: /home/ccuser/workspace/learn-rails_threadly/threadly

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/posts/index.html.erb:14:in `block in _app_views_posts_index_html_erb___3939597186725497532_34806000'
app/views/posts/index.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_posts_index_html_erb___3939597186725497532_34806000'
```

I've also tried f.text and f.text_field for the line in question.

Thank you in advance for any help!  Cheers!

Comment: Please show the entire error.

Comment: Edited to show the full error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is saying

`undefined method "comment" for #<Post id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`

Notice that the post object mounted has only three attributes:

- id
- created_at
- updated_at

It seems you messed things up when creating your migration and runned it before defining that the table should have a "comment" column.

You can recreate your DB in order to make that migration to be executed properly.

- `rake db:drop`
- `rake db:create`
- `rake db:migrate`

After that, make sure your file `schema.rb` shows your `posts` table with the `comment` column.

Comment: This took care of the error, indeed. Thank you for your help.  Codecademy hasn't yet taught me to use the rake db:drop or the rake db:create commands. Their instructions directed me to use rake db:migrate, then rake db:seed. Is it standard procedure to always use drop, then rake, then migrate when you want to update the schema file?

Comment: If you want to update your schema, you'll have to only run rake db:migrate. I told you to drop your database and recreate it because I thought you already have ran your migrations.